# Get client IP address using Nginx and Azure Front Door

Tags: nginx, azure-cdn, azure-front-door

I am using an Azure WebApp (docker-compose) which has Nginx as reverse proxy and .net core app. Last year our number of clients increased a lot and we started using Azure Front Door as CDN for caching static content. Problem is now we no longer are able to get client IP address for our logging SQL table.

This is the code that works without the AFD:

Nginx default.conf:

```
    proxy_set_header          X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header          X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Dotnet Startup.cs:

```
      app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
      {
        ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
      });
```

But adding the AFD it always gets the IP address of the CDN.

I know AFD passes `X-Azure-ClientIP` header, but I was not able to get it in Nginx or dotnet.

Do you know how can I get real client IP address using Azure Front Door, Nginx and dotnet core?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The CDN (which is nothing more then a proxy server + caching) MUST send the real client IP in a specific header (X-Forwarded-For) to NGINX. NGINX can be configured to use this header and replace the IP from the CDN with IP send in the header. Look at the NGINX real_ip module. https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked this way:

1. Nginx:

```
server {
  listen                      8080;
  server_name                 *.pragmaticworkstraining.com *.staging.pragmaticworkstraining.com localhost;
  client_max_body_size        1024M;
  client_header_timeout       36000;
  client_body_timeout         36000; 
  proxy_connect_timeout       75s; 
  proxy_read_timeout          36000; 
  proxy_send_timeout          36000;

  location / {
    proxy_pass                http://web-site:5000;
    proxy_http_version        1.1;
    proxy_set_header          Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header          Connection $http_connection;
    proxy_set_header          Host $host;
    proxy_set_header          X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header          X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_cache_bypass        $http_upgrade;
    gzip                      on;
    gzip_types                text/plain text/css application/xml application/javascript font/woff2 image/x-icon;
  }
}
```

dotnet:

```
string ip = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"].ToString();
string[] ipRange = ip.Split(',');
clientIp = ipRange[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Azure Front Door saves the client IP information in its own logs.  In the Azure Portal you can access these logs by going to the "Logs" blade:

[image: Front Door Logs blade]

You can query the information using Kusto, for example, this query will retrieve the timestamp, request URI, and client IP for all requests in the previous 15 minutes:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where TimeGenerated > now(-15m)
| project TimeGenerated, requestUri_s, clientIp_s
```

If you wanted to pull this information into your own SQL logs you can programmatically retrieve it using an Azure Logic App, Azure Runbook with a Powershell query, or several other solutions.